# Magento 2: Two Prices for the same product

Tags: shipping, magento2.2.6, product-prices

I was wondering does anyone know if Magento 2.2.6 is capable of handling more than one price for each product.

The reason I ask is that I buy in most of the items we sell after they have been ordered. Our suppliers have different prices for shipping to us. Next day which is the most expensive and a cheaper price which takes 4 days for the items to arrive with us.

I am looking to include shipping within the price on the product page and as I have two different prices I would like our customers to see them immediately without having to add to basket and find how much it is at that stage. Is there any extensions or has anyone seen this functionality implemented elsewhere?

Comment: you need to make custom extension for this, which show custom price there.

Answer (score 0):

The approach without using an extension would be to use custom options for your products.

Set the 4-days-price, which I understand is the normal price, as the product's price.

Then add a custom option, for example called "Express shipping" or else, to the product and set the price for this option to the difference you need.

The price on the product page will update automatically as soon as your customer chooses that option.